AC Phasor Angles in Complex Number Analysis
I'm not sure if this problem is unique to me, but it's been breaking my brain for the past few months. While assuming phasor angles for AC circuit analysis using complex numbers, my teacher said that a lagging phasor has a positive phase angle and a leading phasor has a negative phase angle (makes sense as φ is just ωt and lagging is when t is higher). However, when it came to analysing 3 Phase AC circuits, the teacher simply reversed the convention. Lagging phasors were treated to have negative phase angles, as we wrote voltage phasor values for phase voltages. This caused multiple power related formulae to have conjugated current values. Why is this done, and what can I do to remember their convention?
EDIT: Thank you for @periblepsis for pointing this out, I didn't mention what reference phasor we were using. For any circuit, the EMF (or Voltage) phasor was assumed to be the reference (i.e., at an angle zero.) My problem was that while doing single phase AC, lagging currents (say through an inductor) were assumed to have positive phase angle. However, while doing 3 Phase (say RYB), when \$V_{RN}=V_{Ph}*e^{i0}\$, we were asked to assume \$V_{YN}=V_{Ph}*e^{i(-120°)}\$, though Y lagged behind R and hence (at least in my head) should be \$V_{YN}=V_{Ph}*e^{i(+120°)}\$. Hopefully this more properly explains my issue.

I don't know what you are being taught. But the meaning of leading and lagging always requires a reference to be selected. This can either be the voltage vector or the current vector. And I've seen both used. So the voltage could be leading the current, if the current is the reference and if the voltage phase is positive with respect to it. But likewise in the exact same situation the current would be lagging, if the voltage vector was the reference. So you don't write enough for me to tell what situation was going on, before getting into 3-phase power. I have no idea if the following helps or hurts, therefore. You will have to decide. Only you have the fuller context.
In the most compact form, complex voltage is \$\mathbb{V}=V_{_0}\,e^{s\left(t+t_{_\text{V}}\right)}\$ and complex current is \$\mathbb{I}=I_{_0}\,e^{s\left(t+t_{_\text{I}}\right)}\$. It's simple enough and you can use Ohm's Law to apply complex impedance, \$\mathbb{Z}\$. (Note: \$s=\sigma+j\,\omega\$.) \$t_{_\text{V}}\$ and \$t_{_\text{I}}\$ are just time-shifts and can be converted into phase, as I will next show.
For phasors \$\sigma=0\$ so these become \$\mathbb{V}=V_{_0}\,e^{\,j\left(\omega \,t+\omega\,t_{_\text{V}}\right)}\$ and \$\mathbb{I}=I_{_0}\,e^{\,j\left(\omega \,t+\omega\,t_{_\text{I}}\right)}\$. But \$\phi_{_\text{V}}=\omega\,t_{_\text{V}}\$ and \$\phi_{_\text{I}}=\omega\,t_{_\text{I}}\$. So this gets to \$\mathbb{V}=V_{_0}\,e^{\,j\left(\omega \,t+\phi_{_\text{V}}\right)}\$ and \$\mathbb{I}=I_{_0}\,e^{\,j\left(\omega \,t+\phi_{_\text{I}}\right)}\$. One more simplification is that the \$e^{\,j\,\omega\,t}\$ part is taken as granted, since \$\omega\$ in phasor systems is the same throughout. (There's only one \$\omega\$.) So things get really simple with \$\mathbb{V}=V_{_0}\,e^{\,j\,\phi_{_\text{V}}}\$ and \$\mathbb{I}=I_{_0}\,e^{\,j\,\phi_{_\text{I}}}\$. Just a magnitude and phase -- a phasor. (If a value is needed at some instant in time then \$e^{\,j\,\omega\,t}\$ can be re-included back and the real-valued portion of the resulting Euler's used to get that instant's value.)
All is fine, so far. But now if you try to multiply \$\mathcal{Re}\left(\mathbb{V}\cdot\mathbb{I}\right)\$, hoping to get power, you will find that you get \$\mathcal{Re}\left(V_{_0}\,I_{_0}\,e^{\,j\left(\phi_{_\text{V}}+\phi_{_\text{I}}\right)}\right)=V_{_0}\,I_{_0}\,\cos\left(\phi_{_\text{V}}+\phi_{_\text{I}}\right)\$. But you really want the phase difference since if the phase is the same then you want the cosine of zero, which is the difference. So, instead, you take \$\mathcal{Re}\left(\mathbb{V}\cdot\mathbb{I}^*\right)\$ since that will then be \$V_{_0}\,I_{_0}\,\cos\left(\phi_{_\text{V}}-\phi_{_\text{I}}\right)\$. And that's what you want to use for power calculations.
I think you were not dealing with power, earlier, and instead dealing with only current and voltage vectors. But when power was introduced then the conjugate of current was forced; and that negates the current phase. Just note that for power you must negate the current phase.
Or maybe I completely misunderstand your question. I'm just not sure enough about my ability to read between the lines of what you wrote.
